# Assignment from function to variable defined as mutable reference?

Tags: rust, immutability, traits, lifetime, ode

I'm trying to implement the ode_solvers crate to integrate my system of equations. To do so I have a function that calculates what dydx will be and then I call that within the implementation of the system as the example in the documents describe

```rust
type State = DVector<f64>;

impl ode_solvers::System<State> for NBody {
    fn system<'a>(&self, _t: Time, y: &State, mut dy: &'a mut State) {
        
        dy = get_derivatives(y, &self.masses, self.n_objects)
    }
}
```

When I do this I get type mismatch errors as the function get derivatives outputs a State type but dy expects a &mut State.
But if I change the output of the function to a mutable reference then I get lifetime issues I don't know how to resolve.
And finally I keep getting an error that I can't assign to immutable dy.

The example in the [documents](https://srenevey.github.io/ode-solvers/examples/kepler_orbit.html) shows this -

```rust
impl ode_solvers::System<State> for KeplerOrbit {
    // Equations of motion of the system
    fn system(&self, _t: Time, y: &State, dy: &mut State) {
        let r = (y[0] * y[0] + y[1] * y[1] + y[2] * y[2]).sqrt();

        dy[0] = y[3];
        dy[1] = y[4];
        dy[2] = y[5];
        dy[3] = - self.mu * y[0] / r.powi(3);
        dy[4] = - self.mu * y[1] / r.powi(3);
        dy[5] = - self.mu * y[2] / r.powi(3);
    }
}
```

I assume the example works fine because each value being assigned has copy implemented for it but my assignment is a vec itself so it's unclear how to resolve this.

Comment: doing for i in 0..y.len() {dy[i] = temp[i]} where temp is the function output assigned to temp first. seems to have worked. Or at least the errors are gone. Need to test it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to **assign to** the thing that a mutable reference points to, you must **dereference** it; otherwise you're trying to replace the reference in the local variable, which does no good even if you succeeded. These two lines:

```rust
fn system<'a>(&self, _t: Time, y: &State, mut dy: &'a mut State) {     
    ...
    dy = get_derivatives(y, &self.masses, self.n_objects)
```

should instead be

```rust
fn system<'a>(&self, _t: Time, y: &State, dy: &'a mut State) {
    ...
    *dy = get_derivatives(y, &self.masses, self.n_objects);
```

The added dereference `*` operator in `*dy = ...` is what you need. Note also that the variable `dy` does not need to be declared `mut` (because you are not reassigning the reference itself) — that is, you can change `mut dy: &'a mut State` to `dy: &'a mut State`.

The reason this doesn't happen when you are accessing a vector element `dy[i]` is because the indexing operator has a dereference built in; it expands to roughly `*IndexMut::index_mut(&mut dy, i)`, and the extra `&mut` is handled by [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods). (In general, thanks to deref coercion, you can often ignore *extra layers of references*, like `&&Foo` and `&mut &mut Foo`, but you need to be careful with the difference between a specific type and any reference or references to it.)

Comment: Thank you this is useful to know! I would have to keep dy specified as mut in this case simply because the package requires it be declared as mut but thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @thefrollickingnerd When I say `mut` is not required, I mean the `mut` written before the variable name. The `mut` in `&'a mut State` must stay. I edited the answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution -

```rust
fn system(&self, _t: Time, y: &State, dy: &mut State) {
        let out = get_derivatives(y.clone(), &self.masses, self.n_objects);
        for i in 0..y.len() {dy[i] = out[i];}
    }
```